# Email Subscription plugin in octobercms not working

Tags: content-management-system, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I used this plugin in CMSpage. When the subscribe button is clicked no action is performed and redirects to the same page in which the formSubscribe component is added. The users are not added to the subscribers' list either. I added the formUnsubscribe component to another page. The formProfile component is also added to the same page in which there is formSubscribe component. I can't understand what I am doing wrong. The process to add the plugin is also not clear in the documentation provided.

Here is the [link](https://octobercms.com/plugin/jorgeandrade-subscribe)
 to the plugin.

```
 <form name="form-subscribe-andradedev" id="form-subscribe-andradedev" data-request="formSubscribe::onAddSubscriber" data-request-update="'formSubscribe::alert': '#result'">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="* Email" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="latitude">
        <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a javascript issue. Try this checklist;

- Insert a record from the plugin's back-end form and check the event Log for errors ( Settings >> Event Log ). Has the record being created ? Any Errors ?
- Check you browser console to see if there are any Javascript errors. (Combiner file working and all dependencies included e.g jQuery..)
- Add the October [Ajax framework tags](https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/introduction) to your layout if you haven't. As you mentioned if the page is refreshing after form submission **this** is most likely the problem. e.g;

  ```
  <script src="{{ [
      '@jquery'
  ]|theme }}"></script>

  {% framework extras %} <!-- This tag is important -->
  ```
- I haven't used this plugin but looking at the components I suggest you add each one to a separate CMS page because of the redirects. In this case remove the `formProfile` from the `formSubscribe` page and add it somewhere else.

If none of the above solves the problem and there are **no errors**, you should maybe contact the plugin author for support or update your question to include all the code used.

Comment: Yes you were right, now again I am having another issue. The subscriber list is updated in the backend but no email is sent neither does the profile form opens. I have added the code of the form can you please check it.

Comment: which mail driver are you using? Did you update the configuration file with your credentials? Did you try sending a test mail just to make sure the problem isn't from the Plugin? (go to backend settings > mail templates> open any template and click send test)

Comment: I could not understand how to update the configuration files. I tried the test mail is only sent to admin and not to the email I set. https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/octobercms/octobercms-mail-settings

Comment: You can update it from the admin panel as well (Settings > Mail Configuration) you need to add the outgoing email details there such as username, password, host ect.. You can copy these from your service provider.

Comment: which username should be entered?

Comment: You need to tell October how to send emails from the system. e.g if you want to use your gmail account `smriti@gmail.com` then you need to update those details so October is able to authenticate with the provider ( outgoing address, account password, host..).
To get better help over here you should provide more information as regards the mail driver / provider and what have you tried, otherwise it is impossible to guide you.

Comment: I have solved it there was a problem with the configuration. Thank you for your help. I am getting a new problem can you please check it.